# Giving reference to container in NestedList

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to do last example in this page

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/nested_list

and i'm using sencha architect but in the example i have to give a reference to the nestedlist to use detail card of the container however i can't do it because i can't edit the code in sencha architect. What should i do to give a reference in nested list to use container and detail card ?

Comment: have you tried manually adding `id` to your nested list and obtain it later through `Ext.getCmp('your_component_id')` yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view to show record details and show it on a leafitemtap event of the nestedlist. For example you can write an event handler including something like:

```
var details = Ext.create('App.view.RecordDetail');
//lets say txtRecord is a text field in RecordDetail view
Ext.getCmp('txtRecord').setValue(record.get('text')); 
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(details);
```

Also you can have a toolbar containing a back button on your details view for navigating back to the nested list. Or alternatively you can take a look at `Ext.navigation.View` for automatic navigation.